# Grouping/recoding factors in the same data.frame

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=letters[1:26],1:26)
```

And I would like to "re" factor a, b, and c as "a".

How do I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Has anyone tried using this simple method? It requires no special packages, just an understanding of how R treats factors.

Say you want to rename the levels in a factor, get their indices

```
data <- data.frame(a=letters[1:26],1:26)
lalpha <- levels(data$a)
```

In this example we imagine we want to know the index for the level 'e' and 'w'

```
lalpha <- levels(data$a)
ind <- c(which(lalpha == 'e'), which(lalpha == 'w'))
```

Now we can use this index to replace the levels of the factor 'a'

```
levels(data$a)[ind] <- 'X'
```

If you now look at the dataframe factor `a` there will be an X where there was an `e` and `w`

I leave it to you to try the result.

Answer (score 14):

One option is the `recode()` function in package `car`:

```
require(car)
df <- data.frame(a=letters[1:26],1:26)
df2 <- within(df, a <- recode(a, 'c("a","b","c")="a"'))
> head(df2)
  a X1.26
1 a     1
2 a     2
3 a     3
4 d     4
5 e     5
6 f     6
```

Example where `a` is not so simple and we recode several levels into one.

```
set.seed(123)
df3 <- data.frame(a = sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE),
                  b = 1:100)
with(df3, head(a))
with(df3, table(a))
```

the last lines giving:

```
> with(df3, head(a))
[1] b d c e e a
Levels: a b c d e
> with(df3, table(a))
a
 a  b  c  d  e 
19 20 21 22 18
```

Now lets combine levels `a` and `e` into level `Z` using `recode()`

```
df4 <- within(df3, a <- recode(a, 'c("a","e")="Z"'))
with(df4, head(a))
with(df4, table(a))
```

which gives:

```
> with(df4, head(a))
[1] b d c Z Z Z
Levels: b c d Z
> with(df4, table(a))
a
 b  c  d  Z 
20 21 22 37
```

Doing this without spelling out the levels to merge:

```
## Select the levels you want (here 'a' and 'e')
lev.want <- with(df3, levels(a)[c(1,5)])
## now paste together
lev.want <- paste(lev.want, collapse = "','")
## then bolt on the extra bit
codes <- paste("c('", lev.want, "')='Z'", sep = "")
## then use within recode()
df5 <- within(df3, a <- recode(a, codes))
with(df5, table(a))
```

Which gives us the same as `df4` above:

```
> with(df5, table(a))
a
 b  c  d  Z 
20 21 22 37
```

Comment: Does it have to be an ordered factor to be able to use this?

Comment: @Brandon: no, and in the above example it wasn't ordered from the point of view of `with(df, is.ordered(a))`. I'll add another example showing something where `a` isn't as simple as your original.

Comment: @Brandon: Ok, great. So the extra example I added to my answer shows `recode()` working in such an un-ordered factor.

Comment: Is there a way to reference the levels without typing out the label?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean? At some point you're going to have to state which levels you want to merge. So I probably don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, was being dense. I've edited my second example to show what I think you are after.

Comment: I wasn't exactly clear either! Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
df$a[df$a %in% c("a","b","c")] <- "a"
```

---

UPDATE: More complicated factors.

```
Data <- data.frame(a=sample(c("Less than $50,000","$50,000-$99,999",
  "$100,000-$249,999", "$250,000-$500,000"),20,TRUE),n=1:20)
rows <- Data$a %in% c("$50,000-$99,999", "$100,000-$249,999")
Data$a[rows] <- "$250,000-$500,000"
```

Comment: This works well for the example that I provided, but it breaks as soon as I try to use more complicated factor names

Comment: @Brandon could you provide an example of "more complicated factor names"?

Comment: "Less than $50,000","$50,000-$99,999", "$100,000-$249,999", "$250,000-$500,000"

Comment: And to clean up you should do also `levels(df$a) <- levels(df$a)[!levels(df$a)%in%c("b","c")]`

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways.
if you don't want to drop the unused levels, ie "b" and "c", Joshua's solution is probably best.

if you want to drop the unused levels, then

```
df$a<-factor(ifelse(df$a%in%c("a","b","c"),"a",as.character(df$a)))
```

or

```
levels(df$a)<-ifelse(levels(df$a)%in%c("a","b","c"),"a",levels(df$a))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of the chosen answer:

I've found that the easiest way to deal with this is to simply overwrite the factor levels by looking at them and then writing the numbers down to be overwritten.

```
df <- data.frame(a=letters[1:26],1:26)
levels(df)

> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" 
 "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"

levels(df$a)[c(1,2)] <- "c"
summary(df$a)

> c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
  3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```